# declaration the records in C# 9.0 in keyword "data" or "records"?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

is use in keyword data?

```
public data class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

or changes to record ?

```
public record class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They **changed** into `record`.

The definition

```cs
public record class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; init; }
    public string LastName { get; init; }
}
```

is **only valid** record definition now.